# How to recreate Aura code into LWC JS code

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura

I have a LWC code where if you click the button it generates a URL and then opens it. I have another aura component that is launched from a flow and it does the exact same thing as the LWC but this actually works and the LWC is not working. I was wondering if anyone could help me on how to rewrite the aura controller code as a LWC JS code?
Here is the working aura code:

```
Component:
    <aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:availableForFlowActions">
        <aura:attribute name="URLpassing" type="String"/>
    </aura:component>

JS cONTROLLER:
    ({    
        invoke : function(component, event, helper) 
            var URL = component.get("v.URLpassing");
            var redirect = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
       
            // Pass the record ID to the event
            redirect.setParams({
                "url": URL,
            });
            
            // Open the record
            redirect.fire();
        }
    })
```

The url is passed from a flow to this aura component

I want to replicate the controller code into my LWC JS so it behaves the same way. This is what my Lwc is doing:
HTML:

```
<template>
<div>
            <lightning-button class="aButton" label="URLCreator" onclick={UrlCreator}></lightning-button>
        </div>
</template>

JS:
export default class URLCreate extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @api accId;
    @track PageUrl;
URLCreator(event) {
        
        this.PageUrl = '/apex/AVFpage_HTML';
        this.PageUrl += "&accountId="+ this.accId;
        
        
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: this.PageUrl
            }
        }).then(generatedUrl => { //this set of code I dont think is working. I need to replicate this like my aura controller code
            
            sforce.one.navigateToUrl(generatedUrl); 
        });
    }
```

If anymore can help, that would create. Again, since my aura is working, I would like to mimic the functionality/code into my LWC but I dont know how to write that aura functionality as LWC
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.open` method once the URL is generated and the promise is resolved, to navigate using the NavigationMixin.

Try the below code

```
//Navigate to pdf page
UrlCreator() {
    this.PageUrl = '/apex/AVFpage_HTML';
    this.PageUrl += "&accountId="+ this.accId;
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: this.PageUrl
        }
    }).then(generatedUrl => {
        window.open(generatedUrl);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thats what I had originally had but that does not open in Android or mobile apps

Comment: I suggest you add this info in the question that it does not work for a specific device. Is your android app native, hybrid, or Salesforce 1 app?

Comment: srivastava it is on a Android device using SF 1 mobile app